# Least sum of products of powers

Tags: number-theory, optimization

Numbers from the set $\{2^1, 2^2, ..., 2^{10}\}$ are somehow permuted and paired with numbers from the set $\{3^1, 3^2, ..., 3^{10}\}$. Numbers in each pair are multiplied and the products are summed. What is the least sum you can get?

It seems intuitively obvious that you have to pair least power of 2 with highest power of 3, and second least with second highest and so on. In fact, it looks like this "reversing" method works for any two geometric progressions. I wasn't able to provide a strict proof for either though.

Closest I've gotten to the solution is that when we exchange elements from two pairs, the sum gets higher. I've also tried induction, but then the induction step is not very clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More generally, if we have $a_1 < a_2 < \dotsc < a_n$ and $b_1 < b_2 < \dots < b_n$, then

$$\min \left\{ \sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_{\sigma(k)} : \sigma \in S_n\right\} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_{n+1-k}.$$

There are only finitely many permutations of $n$ elements, so the minimum is attained for some permutation, and it suffices to show that none of the other permutations attains a minimum. So suppose $\tau$ is a permutation other than $k \mapsto n+1-k$. Then there are $i < j$ with $\tau(i) < \tau(j)$. But then

$$a_ib_{\tau(i)} + a_j b_{\tau(j)} - a_i b_{\tau(j)} - a_j b_{\tau(i)}
= (a_j- a_i)\bigl(b_{\tau(j)} - b_{\tau(i)}) > 0,$$

so the permutation

$$\pi \colon k \mapsto \begin{cases} \tau(j) &, k = i\\ \tau(i) &, k = j\\ \tau(k) &, k \notin \{i,j\}\end{cases}$$

yields a smaller sum than $\tau$.